# Getting data if already exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem with SQL query. I have a history table, where orders have logged all changes of status. What I want to do is get order that have specific status.

I used this query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    HistoryDate
FROM 
    schema.History
WHERE 
    OrderID = 123123
    AND OrderStatusID = 10
    AND OrderID IN (SELECT TOP 1 OrderID
                    FROM schema.History
                    WHERE OrderStatusId = 5
                      AND OrderID = 123123)
```

Query results satisfies, but I want to avoid referring to same table two times.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

What I didn't mention before is fact that when there are status 5 and 10 I want `HistoryDate` from status 10, if there is no status 10 I want NULL, and when there is only status 10 I want `HistoryDate` of status 10 also.

Comment: I thin you want ...AND (OrderStatusID = 10 OR  OrderStatusId = 5) instead of that subquery

Comment: It makes sense, in my table there are many entries connected to one orderId, the thing that is different is OrderStatusID

Comment: You seem to be wanting to find orders that had a specific status, but now have a different one. You could always just grab all history for a specific order, and then in code examine the differences.

Comment: @Mihai: Adding OR might help, but what if there will be only status 5 in history? I dont want any result then, status 10 and 5 MUST exist

Comment: What specific status do you want?

Comment: `WHERE OrderID = 123123 AND OrderID IN (` ... these two predicates don't make any sense when put together.

Comment: What is the big deal with referring to the same table two times?   Your edit states you when there is status of 10 you want results.

Answer (score 0):

In general you have to use a subquery if you want to find another record in a second status and the same `OrderID`. But you could use `EXISTS` which is clearer in my opinion:

```
SELECT TOP 1 h1.HistoryDate
FROM schema.History h1
WHERE h1.OrderID = @OrderID 
AND h1.OrderStatusID = 10
AND EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM schema.History h2
   WHERE h1.OrderID = h2.OrderID
   AND   h2.OrderStatusID = 5
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any way to do this without using two tables.  Logically, you're defining an intersection of two sets, and that usually means two tables or a join.

@TimSchmelter's query with EXISTS is preferred, and may improve performance although keep in mind that `TOP` without `ORDER BY` is non-deterministic (i.e., not reliable) so you're not guaranteed to get the most recent or oldest HistoryDate.  You're just guaranteed to get *a* HistoryDate.

If you just don't want a subquery, you could do a self-join:

```
SELECT TOP 1 h1.HistoryDate
FROM schema.History h1
INNER JOIN schema.History h2
    ON h1.OrderID = h2.OrderID
WHERE h1.OrderID = 123123
    AND h1.OrderStatusID = 10
    AND h2.OrderStatusId = 5
```

Depending on your setup, that may perform better or may perform worse, although it *should* perform about the same.

Again, though, `TOP` without `ORDER BY` is non-deterministic.  I strongly encourage you to add an `ORDER BY h1.HistoryDate` or `ORDER BY h1.HistoryDate DESC` or you may very well get unexpected results if any Order has multiple history dates with OrderStatusID of `10`.